# EmacsW32 Cygwin shell problem

Tags: emacs

I have EmacsW32 and Cygwin shell integrated

when running cygwin-shell in EmacsW32 at prompt  i see this

```
^[]0;~^G
^[[32mtroydm@ds-dev-025 ^[33m~^[[0m
```

instead of normal prompt.

if i run cygwin shell from desktop icon it's working correctly

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those are ansi color control sequences.  if you are using shell-mode, then you can get emacs to interpret those sequences using the ansi-color support.  add something like this to your .emacs file:

```
(require 'ansi-color)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Comment: it helped however i still have ^[]0;~^G  left but the colors on the second line are working correctly thx

Comment: that part looks like some attempt to set the terminal title using a special print sequence.  you should probably disable anything like that in emacs term.  in your shell config file, check for an env var named EMACS to be set to 1 when your shell is running inside emacs.

Comment: I've managed to fix it using export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "